# How do I remove specific beta testers from my google play game, or let them at least rate the app publicly?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-games

This seems simple enough, but I'm completely stuck.
Even if I pause the test track, all of my testers are still part of the beta and can't rate my game publicly.

Any idea how to get over this?